# Suddenly getting 403 (Forbidden) errors for all assets in Google Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I built several sites for clients which use Google Storage for their larger media. They have all been running fine since 2010, then in the past few days all of them started getting the 403 errors.

I scanned back through my Google Storage emails, and I don't see any announcements that would be relevant. No files have changed in the client's sites.

Is anyone having a similar issue? What can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a message returned with the 403 response? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to have left this hanging. The issue was caused by a credit card expiration date mismatch.

Facepalm.

Thanks for your attention Nikita.